# LPC17xx sleep modes and software reset error when invoked in interrupt

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I have a problem with both the sleepmodes and NVIC_reset(), aka software reset.

The problem is present on two totally distinct boards, both with a LPC1769 uC.

If I enter the sleepmode within main() or another function, except an interrupt routine, the sleep mode is working perfecly. The uC wakes also with an external interrupt on EINT0. The reset function does its job also well in the main function.

But when a sleepmode or reset request is invoked inside an interrupt routine trouble starts. The sleep mode lookes to be entered but the uC does not wake up anymore.

E.g. enter a sleep mode with EINT1 and wake with EINT0:

```
void EINT0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  EXTI_ClearEXTIFlag(0);
}

void EINT1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    EXTI_ClearEXTIFlag(1);
    CLKPWR_Sleep();
}
```

Anybody a clue why this does not work properly?

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your interrupt priorities?

> 34.3.5.2.1 Wakeup from WFI or sleep-on-exit
>
>            Normally, the processor wakes up only when it detects an exception with sufficient priority
>            to cause exception entry.

Comment: Yes and it should work using the default priority list (18 is higher then 19). But only when I change the priority manually the interrupt works while sleeping.

Comment: The problem is somewhat more complicated. The thing I want to accomplish is to make an on/off button which first puts the uC in sleep mode and when pressed for a second time (same button same interrupt) resets the uC using a watchdog timer. This works well when using two buttons with two distinct interrupt routines. But when using only one interrupt routine (EINT0) I end up in the with the same problem that the uC does not wake anymore due to the fact that when the uC has entered sleep mode it is still in the interrupt routine with the same priority.

Comment: Changing the priority to a lower (higher prio) value before entering sleep does not help either.

You would think that this kind of functionality is required very often, but I do not have seen anybody doing it. At least on the web.

This is the code:

    void EINT0_IRQHandler(void)
    {
        EXTI_ClearEXTIFlag(0);
        CLKPWR_Sleep();
        WDT_Init(WDT_CLKSRC_IRC, WDT_MODE_RESET);
        WDT_Start(1);
    }

Does someone knows a way of accomplishing such a functionality?

Comment: @wlamers No, this is not required often, as going to sleep in an interrupt is unusual. In most systems you sleep when you have nothing more to do, to save power, usually in the idle loop. In your case I would use the interrupt just for waking up. For going to sleep I would sample the button cyclically in a task (and also do debouncing).